# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I was trying to sort my ArrayList.

```
java.util.ArrayList arList= new java.util.ArrayList();  
   arList=getList();    
   java.util.Collections.sort(arList);
```

where my getList() function here

```
public ArrayList getList() throws Exception
{
ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
//Query executing here..............!
            while (rs.next()) 
                {
                HashMap hashList = new HashMap();
                hashList.put("name",rs.getString(1));
                hashList.put("id",rs.getBigDecimal(2));
                listItems.add(hashList);
                }
          return listItems;
}
```

But I am facing error :**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable**

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to sort the `ArrayList`? Your list contains a number of `HashMaps`. Are you trying to sort it based on the key of the map or the value of the map?

Comment: Why are you using `HashMap`s here?  You should be creating a proper object class to hold names and IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*First Thing* -

```
java.util.ArrayList arList= new java.util.ArrayList();  
arList=getList();
```

You create the first instance unnecessary.

*Second Thing* -

```
ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
```

This list contains list HashMap And HashMap does not implements Comparable.

```
java.util.Collections.sort(arList);

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

List contain(`T`) must extends Comparable.

that is why it populate `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `Collections.sort()`, Lists (and arrays) of objects that implement this interface **Comparable**. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 2):

This way you can achieve a Sorted Map

```
public class MapUsingSort {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Map<Integer, String> abc = new HashMap<>();
abc.put(3, "a");
abc.put(6, "b");
abc.put(1, "c");
abc.put(4, "h");
abc.put(10, "k");
abc.put(9, "x");

 // Map is stored in ArrayList
List<Entry<Integer,String>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer,String>>(abc.entrySet());


Collections.sort(sortedEntries, new Comparator<Entry<Integer,String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Integer, String> a, Entry<Integer, String> b) 
    {
        //Sorting is done here make changes as per your need 
        // swap a and b for descending order 

        return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());   
    }
   });

for (Object object : sortedEntries) {

    //print your data in your own way
    System.out.println((Map.Entry)object);
   }
  }
}
```

For further in detail visit [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

*

> This is my first answer on stackOverflow hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code seems weird, you are adding a newly created HashMap object into your list in each iteration of the loop. Anyway, I'll not discuss it. Maybe you should specify your ArrayList like this: `ArrayList<HashMap>`
But that is not enough. If you have a list of a specific type and wanna sort them, then your **type** (in this case HashMap) should implement `Comparable` interface. HashMap doesn't implement `Comparable` interface. Read the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

You should implement your own **Comparator** as a solution, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

> All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

This should say it all.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the compiler error is trying to convey you in the best way it can that it cannot compare `HashMaps`, that you have inside your list..

First you should declare your list as generic list like this: -

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> hashList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want to sort `List<HashMap>`, you need to have a `Comparator` to sort.. You cannot sort it using natural ordering.. Because your `HashMap` does not implement `Comparable` interface..

You can only compare two instances if they are comparable..

*EDIT: - Well, I think you will need two `Comparators` here.. One for your `List` and one for your `HashMap` inside the `List`.. But I'm not pretty sure about it whether it would work..

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort(List<T>)` requires an object `T` of type `Comparable`. That means any object that implements Comparable interface will work. Refer [this](
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

In your case you are trying to sort an `ArrayList` that contains a `HashMap`, which does not implements `Comparable` interface. So. the code fails.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap does not implement the Comparable interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). As far as I know the Collections.sort()-Method can only sort natural values.But you can write your own comparator and sort your list as you wish. The Collections.sort()-Method is overloaded therefore

Answer (score 1):

For something to be sorted, it must implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, which is something which the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does not.

As a result, when you try to sort your list of HashMaps your code fails.

If you really need to be able to compare HashMaps, you could create your own HashMap, something like so:

```
public class MyHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K, V> implements Comparable<HashMap<K,V>>
{
    ...
    public int compareTo(HashMap<K,V> comparer)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Because  `java.util.Collections.sort(arList);`
**arList** contains the `HashMap hashList = new HashMap();`
unfortunately hashMap did not implement the `Comparable or Comparator interface.`
and **Collections.sort()** method will sort on the implementation of

```
 Comparable or Comparator interface.
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess the error happened on line Collections.sort().

If you want to use sort, the objects in the list must be Comparable. Otherwise how java is gonna sort it?

HashMap is not Comparable. You can extend HashMap and implement Comparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to know **how to add comparable** it's easy

just add

`YourClassName implement comparable{ }`

you can refer this! :)

[www.w3schools.blog/comparable-comparator-java](http://www.w3schools.blog/comparable-comparator-java)